# Using a thermos flask as a vacuum chamber

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, vacuum

I want to create a vacuum chamber (-900 mbar) that can withstand heat (120°C).
I thought about using a pressure cooker similar to most DIY vacuum chambers, but then thought about using a large food thermos flask (since you get insulation for "free").

Is there any risk/downside I might be overlooking?

Comment: Well, you'd need to check whether the flask (or any container) can withstand the vacuum.

Comment: Containers and pressure vessels are built to contain pressure ; their resistance to vacuum is only incidental. In a refinery the vacuum pipe stills  stand out because of heavy external rings . And that is for  a design of about  9/10 of a Bar total pressure..